# Tideman CS50 C++ Sort function

Tags: c++, cs50

I have already passed the test but I don't get it. This is the correct code.

```
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count-1 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<pair_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser]<preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser])
            {
                pair temp = pairs[i];
                pairs[i]=pairs[j];
                pairs[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    
    return;
}
```

This is my old code. As you can see, I simply move the swap part into the sort_pairs code and it works suddenly.

```
void swap (pair a, pair b)
{
     pair temp = pairs[a];
     pairs[a]=pairs[b]
     pairs[b]=temp;
}

void sort_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count-1 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<pair_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser]<preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser])
            {
                swap (pairs[i],pairs[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    
    return;
}
```

Now I understand the issue is passing by value so technically I am just swapping a copy of a and b instead of the original value i and j. However, what confuse me the most is when do we need to use a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum (int a, int b);

int main (void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    x = sum (x,y);
    printf("%i",x);
}

int sum (int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b);
}
```

this will return 3 perfectly. However, isn't the function sum is changing the copy of x instead of the "real" x? Because if we do the same for swap, it won't work (like below.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int a, int b);

int main (void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    swap (x,y);
    printf("x=%i and y=%i",x,y);
}

void swap (int a, int b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
    return;
}
```

x will still remain the original x and y stay the original y.

Comment: What is "Tideman CS50" and why is it important to your question?

Comment: It is a homework in week3 of a beginner programming course CS50. I believe I get the answer I want. It is related to change it locally or a copy of it. @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taking the `pair`s by value:

```
void swap (pair a, pair b)     // a is a copy of pairs[i] and b is a copy of pairs[j]
```

The change you make to `a` and `b` inside the function will be discarded when the function exits. `a` and `b` are local to the function only.

Take them by reference (`pair&`) instead and then `swap` the correct variables:

```
void swap (pair& a, pair& b) { // a is a ref to pairs[i] and b is a ref to pairs[j]
     pair temp = a;            // temp is copy constructed from pairs[i]
     a = b;                    // pairs[i] is copy assigned from pairs[j]
     b = temp;                 // pairs[j] is copy assigned from temp
}
```

Sidenote: There's an excellent `swap` utility in the standard library called [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

In your `sum` function, there is `a`, `b` and what can be seen as an unnamed temporary variable involved. It's the return value. It'll maybe be clearer if I show it by adding it:

```
int sum (int a, int b) {
    int temp = a + b;
    return temp;
}
```

No changes are done to `a` and `b` and you `return` the result of the calculation. In the `swap` function, you are supposed to change the variables used as input which is why you need to use references to those variables. You could for example write another add-function like this:

```
void add_x_to_y(int x, int& y) {
    y += x;
}
```

Here `x` is taken by value and `y` by reference, because we're supposed to add `x` to `y`. The change made to `y` inside the function will then be made directly to the variable passed to the function as `y`.

> what confuse me the most is when do we need to use a pointer.

In no case here is a pointer used. Only references and values.

Comment: Beware that if there is `using namespace std;`, there could be conflicts between `std::swap` and any of the OP's functions called `swap`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The homemade `pair` makes me think that either 1) this is done in a separate namespace, or 2) `using namespace std;` isn't used (because almost everything one `#include`s will include `<utility>`).

Comment: I have wrote this as a data structure before for pair.````typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;````

Comment: @jessycaaaa Are you planning to use this in `C`? If not, for `C++` just do: `struct pair { int winner; int loser; };` and `pair` will automatically be `typedef`ined. A note: The standard also includes a class template for pairs, so you could use `using pair = std::pair<int, int>;` to create an alias to it. The standard `std::pair` has the members `first` and `second` instead of your `winner` and `loser`.

Comment: @TedLyngmoThanks. I understand the swap part. However, I am slightly confused when I should use a pointer because for some functions like adding 2 integer together, it works perfectly fine. For example, `int add (int a) { a=a+10;} `

Comment: @jessycaaaa In the code you've shown there's no need for _any_ pointer. I (and many others) try to only use pointers when dealing with polymorphism. There are exceptions of course, but in general, don't use them if you don't need to. A _reference_ to an existing object, is much more comprehensible.

In your example, there are no pointers either and it's also causing _undefined behavior_ since the function is not returning anything but claims to return `int`.

Comment: @jessycaaaa You ask a question and someone tries to answer. I find it a bit impolite that you don't stick around to give feedback or to reject or even accept the possible answer you've gotten. Popping up one week later to ask something unrelated and then disappearing again doesn't want me to try to answer more of your questions to be frank.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am truly sorry if I make you feel bad. I didn't intend to do so. Sorry. I don't code full time and i can only squeeze tiny bit of time to do it whenever I can. Also, I tried to re-write my code and experiment it a bit before keep asking for help without my own effort. I am sincere sorry if you feel that way. I am truly glad that you still stick around and reply.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I aint trying to have excuses. I was reading a few more questions and also the manuals of C to figure out when I need to use it before reaching out to you again. I have been trying to figure out when I should use pointer and it has been on my mind for a few days. I didn't reach out right away as I would personally find another person annoying if they didn't even try to solve the issue themselves. sorry for the confusion and misinterpretation.

Comment: @jessycaaaa I was perhaps a bit harsh in my previous comment so I'll try to explain why: When asking questions here, prepare yourself to be able to stick around to answer follow-up questions for an hour our two. When someone has given an answer, you may yourself ask for clarification if you don't understand the answer or accept the answer. Acknowledging that you've seen the answer and saying that you need time to digest it would also be an ok response.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Glad to know. :) I just didn't want you to feel bad when i have no intention of such. Let me show you some codes I have written recently then you may understand further the question i followed up isn't coming from nowhere.

Comment: @jessycaaaa Sure. If it's related to the question you can just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63492340/edit) the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not sure if I do it correctly but I have added more comments.

Comment: @jessycaaaa Ok, I added further explanations.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you! I think i can fully understand soon. And the new swap one (void swap (int a, int b)) doesn't work because it was not returning anything. The swap might have been done inside the function but it can't be reflect in the main. Am I correct? If this is true, then I think I finally get the full picture.

Comment: @jessycaaaa Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks! I fully understand now!

Comment: @jessycaaaa Great! Is there any reason why you don't want to accept the answer?

Comment: @jessycaaaa I am inclined to return to my original impression after which you got me to put even more effort into explaining this. You say that my answer helped you to understand this fully and yet you don't accept it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Didn't know i have to do it. thought up is already sufficient.

Comment: @jessycaaaa You don't have to but it's the appropriate thing to do when the question you 've asked has gotten an answer that explains what's going on, or in some other way solves the problem.